# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_login1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.login1'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert some data to the sql server but I am getting the error message like "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_login1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.login1'. The statement has been terminated.". I have tried to remove the primary key constraint from the table, after that I see that it is inserting more then two similar kind of data into the table. My code is

```
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        str = "Insert into login1 values ('" + txtbx_Uname.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Pwd.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Email.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Dob.Text + "', " + txtbx_Phone.Text + ")";
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lbl_Error.Visible = true;
        lbl_Error.Text = "Registration Success";
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if(n==1)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        lbl_Error.Visible = true;
        lbl_Error.Text = "SQL Server Error. Pleaase try after sometime";
    }
}
```

Comment: @COLDTOLD I am using Email address as primary key

Comment: then you have to check if the user with the same email already exists before doing insert

Comment: your problem is that you insert multiple data with same primary key

Comment: @COLDTOLD am wondering why one insert statement is inserting more then one record at a time? Please help me.

Comment: [Little Bobby tables alert!](http://xkcd.com/327/) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - that's open to SQL injection attacks. Instead: use **parametrized queries!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and
 `int n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` which will do the same job here.
If you want the status of new record that has been inserted to the table, then change the query to stored procedure or use another query for find out the count of record with the field mentioned.

try the following code.

```
    protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            str = "Insert into login1 values ('" + txtbx_Uname.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Pwd.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Email.Text + "', '" + txtbx_Dob.Text + "', " + txtbx_Phone.Text + ")";
     " _    
    & "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS int32;"
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);    
      int n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());  

            if(n==1)
            {
     lbl_Error.Visible = true;
            lbl_Error.Text = "Registration Success";  
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            con.Close();
           }
     }
        catch
        {
            lbl_Error.Visible = true;
            lbl_Error.Text = "SQL Server Error. Pleaase try after sometime";
        }

}
```

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, Can you please check this code once again? Actually, I am unable to understand this code. what is  " _  & "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS int32;" after the str? and under if statement I think only one code that is "lbl_Error.Visible = true;" will execute? Can you please edit this code again?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code. @@IDENTITY will return the last identity value. if no rows affected it will return null. The problem with your code was you were using executenonquery and executescalar which will insert the record twice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to **catch the exception and then tell the user that the email already exists**. This link may help you : [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/259032/Violation-of-PRIMARY-KEY-constraint-PK_LogIn-Canno)

Comment: can you please tell me why the insert statement is inserting more then one record at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The **[PRIMARY KEY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)** constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.

Primary keys must contain unique values.

A primary key column cannot contain NULL values.

Each table should have a primary key, and each table can have only ONE primary key.

**Before Insertion**

You need to check the new inserting values are present in database or not. If data is not there in database then insert the new values to the database, other wise throw an message to the user "**Data is already present for given input**".